# RewriteCond using PHP and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying perform a conditional RewriteCond using PHP and htaccess. The idea is to read vanity URLS from JSON file and do the redirection accordingly within the PHP file.

It works if it needs to be redirected to another URL as shown in the code using headers.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $2 !^(redirect\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?l=$2 [L]
```

redirect.php

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$found = true;
if($found){
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header(sprintf('Location: %s', 'https://www.google.com'));
}else{//no redirection is need, stay in the same URL
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url)); //throw error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
}
```

However it should not be redirected if the "found" condition is not met as shown and at the moment I am trying to redirect to the same page using the $url variable, and it returns the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". Is there another way to handle this part of the code efficiently?

Comment: The client will get the 301, will follow the forward (which points to the exact same URL) and gets redirect again. This would be an infinite loop. Can you give a short example which URL you are calling and what you actually want the server to do when you call the URL?

Comment: @Kryptur, this does not include the entire logic. However, what I want to do is, I want to stay in the same page if the $found is false. In that case the current page URL will be assigned to the $url variable.

Comment: You save the current URL to the `$url` variable - and if `$found == false` you still set a 301 header and redirect from the current URL to the current URL.
If I'm still getting you wrong please be more precise about what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Kryptur, yes that's correct. All I want to do is to stay in the same page of no redirect is found (govern by the $found) variable. However, if I don't include anything in the 'else' block it'll stay in the 'redirect.php' file. Is there any other way to achieve this? My main goal is to maintain all the redirects within a JSON file populated by another system.

Comment: I just submitted an answer to avoid a lengthy discussion here - I made some assumptions though cause the information is not part of your question. So if I'm totally wrong with my assumptions please be more specific and **give an example** of an URL for the else part as well as the expected result so I can edit the answer accordingly ;)

Answer (score 1):

So based on the comments I guess I can provide an appropriate answer.
So your goal is to react to the called URL and redirect based on if the URL is "known" to your system (`$found`) or not? If this is the case: Is it correct that you want to redirect to Google when `$found` is true? I don't really understand the purpose of it - maybe you mean `!$found`? So all unknown requests are redirected to Google?

Based on these assumptions you can still display content from a different PHP or HTML file on your own server without redirecting the client.

Assume the user calls `https://example.org/some/fancy/page`. This will be redirected to your `redirect.php`, where you can read the `some/fancy/page` part from `$_GET["l"]`.

When your JSON file looks something like this (please provide an actual example if this assumption is totally wrong).

```
{
    "some/fancy/page": "views/page1.html",
    "some/other/page": "views/page2.html"
}
```

Your redirect.php can then check this JSON dictionary for known and unknown requests and redirect or load content based on the result:

```php
$called = $_GET["l"]; // contains "some/fancy/page"
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("path_to_json"), true);

$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Check if the called URL is part of your JSON file.
$found = isset($json[$called]);

if(!$found) { // Note the ! from my assumption
  // We did not find this -> redirect to google
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header(sprintf('Location: %s', 'https://www.google.com'));
} else {
  // Page is found on the local server - load from the file listed in JSON
  // (views/page1.html) and send it to the client.
  echo file_get_contents($json[$called]);  

  /**
  // In case your JSON contains external URLs, e.g. https://fancypage.org for "some/fancy/page", you can still use redirection
  // This will, however, not end up on your own server and thus will not trigger the rewrite rule.
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header(sprintf('Location: %s', $json[$called]));
  **/
}
```

Comment: @Krytur,  appreciate your effort. According to my requirement, if not found (!$found) it should stay in the same URL which we've already assigned to the "$url" variable even though if the page does not exist / not valid (at the moment its redirecting to google.com).

Comment: So please give a concrete example...
What does "not found" mean? Where is it not found? In your JSON file? What does "stay in the same URL" mean? The URL rewriting will not actually change the URL for the client. You then want to display the file that would have been displayed when URL rewriting would have been turned off?

Comment: Not found means when the given URL for instance "https://example.org/some/fancy/page" does not correspond to any value in the JSON. So it will be null and in that case the user will stay in the same page. So what I am trying to achieve is is basically a redirect mechanism where the URLs are maintained within another system and do the redirection if applicable else stay in the given URL. Is there any other way to achieve this without having to use RewriteRule?   I already have the backend system that maintains all the vanity URLs. Only issue is to create the bridge between .htaccess and PHP.

Comment: Again - what does "stay in the same page" mean? Do you have any content to show there? You can use a Rewrite Rule that only rewrites to the redirect.php when the file the URL is addressing does not exists, for example.

Comment: It means, it could be a valid page with content or a 404 & etc